# Find the matrix maximizing a summation of bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, spectral-norm

Given $d, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_k, y_k \in \mathbb{R}^d$, for $1 \leq k \leq n$,
we want to find
$\arg \max_{A: ||A||_2 = 1} \sum_k \langle x_k, A y_k \rangle$,
where $||\cdot||_2$ denotes spectral norm.
I can see that this is a linear combination of $A_{ij}$'s, where the coefficient of $A_{ij}$ is
$\sum_k (x_k)_i (y_k)_j$.
But I cannot proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the matrix whose $j$-th column for each $j$ is $x_j$ and define $Y$ analogously. Let $U\Sigma V^T$ be a singular value decomposition of $XY^T$ and let $B=U^TAV$. Then $\|A\|_2=\|B\|_2$. Also, when $\|B\|_2=1$, the norm of every column of $B$ must be $\le1$. In particular, we have $|b_{kk}|\le 1$ for each $k$. Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\max_{\|A\|_2=1}\sum_k\langle x_k,Ay_k\rangle
&=\max_{\|A\|_2=1}\langle XY^T,A\rangle_F\\
&=\max_{\|A\|_2=1}\langle U\Sigma V^T,A\rangle_F\\
&=\max_{\|B\|_2=1}\langle \Sigma,B\rangle_F\tag{1}\\
&=\max_{\|B\|_2=1}\sum_k\sigma_kb_{kk}\\
&\le\max_{\|B\|_2=1}\sum_k\sigma_k\quad(\because |b_{kk}|\le1)\tag{2}\\
&=\|\Sigma\|_{\mathrm{tr}}\\
&=\|XY^T\|_{\mathrm{tr}}
\end{align}
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_\mathrm{tr}$ denotes the trace norm (a.k.a. nuclear norm or Schatten $1$-norm) of a matrix. Clearly, equality holds in $(2)$ above when $b_{11}=\cdots=b_{dd}=1$. Therefore $B=I$ is an optimal solution to the transformed problem $(1)$ (and such it is the only solution if $XY^T$ is nonsingular), $A=UV^T$ is an optimal solution to the original optimisation problem, and the maximum objective function value is $\|XY^T\|_{\mathrm{tr}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand the overall idea! Just a small question. I think $\max_{\|A\|_2=1}\sum_k\langle x_k,Ay_k\rangle = \max_{\|A\|_2=1}  \langle \sum_k x_k y^T_k,A\rangle$, but how is that equal to $\max_{\|A\|_2=1}\langle XY^T,A\rangle$?

Comment: @VezenBU It is because $\sum_kx_ky_k^T=XY^T$. This is just the usual matrix multiplication. E.g. $x_1y_1^T+x_2y_2^T=\pmatrix{x_1&x_2}\pmatrix{y_1^T\\ y_2^T}$.

Comment: Ah I see! I think I misunderstood the definition of $X$ and $Y$!

Comment: @VezenBU Sorry, there were some mistakes in my answer, but they are corrected now.